# Java Spring Web Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to write a API interface where an incoming HTTP request must be authenticated against the username and password in the db. It is a case where 2 servers need to authenticate the request with a 3rd party server to see if it is valid. The scenario is this:

1. A requesting server sends an user session ID via HTTP POST.
2. My application sends the session ID the another 3rd party server which returns the username.
3. My application checks the username against my db and sets the session token manually.
4. Subsequent requests to my API will need the username and password in the POST header using Basic Authentication.

I have SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
   @Configuration
   @Order(1)
   public class MyAPISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService() {
            return new MyUserDetailsService();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.eraseCredentials(false)
                    .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService())
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            List<String> PATHS_WEB_PERMIT_ALL = new ArrayList<String>();
            PATHS_WEB_PERMIT_ALL.add("/rest/myApi/verifyUser");
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(StringUtils.toStringArray(PATHS_WEB_PERMIT_ALL)).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/myApi/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
            http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

and my userDetailsService:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("Finding user: {}", username);
        CommUser commUser = commUserService.findByUsernameWithRoles(username);
        if (commUser == null) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to find user by username!" + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
        } else {
            commUser.setAuthorities(createAuthorities(commUser));
            return commUser;
        }
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> createAuthorities(CommUser commUser) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        List<CommRoleFunctionMode> commRoleFunctionModes = roleFunctionModeRepository.findByCommRoleIn(commUser.getCommRoles());
        for (CommRoleFunctionMode commRoleFunctionMode : commRoleFunctionModes) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(commRoleFunctionMode.getCommFunction().getFunctionName()));
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(commRoleFunctionMode.getCommFunction().getFunctionName() + commRoleFunctionMode.getCommMode().getModeName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Autowired
    private CommUserService commUserService;

    @Autowired
    private CommRoleFunctionModeRepository roleFunctionModeRepository;
```

and my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/myApi/")
public class MyApiController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApiController.class);

    @PostMapping("verifyUser")
    public ResponseEntity verifyUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserKeyDto userKeyDto, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ProviderManager  providerManager) {
        if (myApiRestService.myApiLoginValidate(userKeyDto, httpRequest, providerManager)) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("The username is incorrect!", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyApiRestService myApiRestService;
}
```

and my MyApiRestService (This is where the bulk of the verifying takes place):

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"myApiRestService"})
public class MyApiRestService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApiRestService.class);
    
    @Transactional
    public boolean myApiLoginValidate(UserKeyDto userKeyDto, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ProviderManager providerManager) {
        String verifyUserUrl = environment.getProperty("api.url") + "/verifyUser";
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(userKeyDto.getSessionId(), headers);
        
        UserKeyDto returnedUserKeyDto = restTemplate.postForObject(verifyUserUrl, request, UserKeyDto.class);
        
        UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(returnedUserKeyDto.getUsername());
          
        if(userDetails==null) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            session = httpRequest.getSession();   
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(),
                userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(httpRequest));
        Authentication authenticatedUser = providerManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
        // setting role to the session
        session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext());    
        
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
```

UserKeyDto:

```
public class UserKeyDto  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2440534315863428792L;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "SessionId is required!")
    private String sessionId;
    
    private String username;
}
```

But I am getting error upon HTTP request:

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.()
> at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)

It seems the Controller cannot instantiate the ProviderManager.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a possible solution, but I'm not sure about it: remove the ProviderManager parameter from your controller's method in MyApiController:

```
@PostMapping("verifyUser")
public ResponseEntity verifyUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserKeyDto userKeyDto, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    if (myApiRestService.myApiLoginValidate(userKeyDto, httpRequest)) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("The username is incorrect!", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Configure ProviderManager in your SecurityConfig class:

```
@Bean
public ProviderManager providerManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
    return new ProviderManager(providers);
}
```